# Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: Like methods do not support null

Tags: c#, null, request.querystring, notsupportedexception

I am checking a search box if the query is empty. If it is empty, then show a query empty error message. However, it bypasses all of my checks for an empty query and goes straight to my ExecuteQuerySearch method then errors (Like methods do not support null.) within my search method that is located within my SearchHelper.cs. It doesn't like that the null object is going through my search method

```
            //If no query show empty query error
        if (query == Request.QueryString[QueryStrings.EmptyQuery] || query.Equals(null) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(query) || query == TranslateText(Dictionary.Keys.KeywordSearch))
        {
            phNoQuery.Visible = true;
            return;
        }

        _totalResults = string.IsNullOrEmpty(scope) ? SearchHelper.ExecuteQuerySearch(query, Model.Divisions).ToList() : SearchHelper.ExecuteQuerySearch(query).ToList();
        resultsCount = _totalResults.Count();
```

Part of my ExecuteQuerySearch method within SearchHelper.cs:

```
    using (var searchContext = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(GetSitecoreSearchIndex()).CreateSearchContext())
        {
                //Errors at allItems
                var allItems = searchContext.GetQueryable<SearchItem>()
                    .Where(GetQueryExpression(QueryType.Content, query))
                    .Where(predicate)
                    .Where(GetContent())
                    .GetResults();
                var hits = allItems.Hits.Where(x => x.Document.AbstractTitle != null).ToList();
                return hits.Select(x => x.Document).ToList();

        }
```

I would like to do the check before executing the search method, but any suggestions or help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Where is query set?  By the way, query.Equals(null) will throw an exception if query is actually null.

Comment: string query = Request.QueryString[QueryStrings.Query];
            var scope = Request.QueryString[QueryStrings.Scope];

Comment: Actually when I debug and I have a breakpoint where I am checking for if the string is empty/null, it goes past the check into the method and throws the exception.

Comment: If you are setting query = Request.QueryString[QueryStrings.Query] - then why are you using Request.QueryString[QueryStrings.Query] again in your if statement?  Also, what is QueryStrings.EmptyQuery?

Comment: public static class QueryStrings
    {
        public static string EmptyQuery = "eq";
        public static string Query = "q";
        public static string Scope = "s"; } It adds the query string eq=t if it is an empty query string. @Mike

Comment: @dg99 When editing a post, please attempt to fix more than just a single problem with the post (like tag edits), especially if your changes require that 4 other users read your edit and approve it.

Comment: @Yakk Unfortunately, I do not write the rules for how the edit queue works.  I will be happy, however, to support any recommendations you may make on that topic on meta.  Until such time, I will continue to try to de-pollute my question list in response to people using tags incorrectly.

Comment: @dg99 simply fix other issues with the post, or earn another 500 reputation.  I mean, can you really not see any other things you could improve in the above post?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the linq statement to an if statement and it fixed the code. I was passing in a null query regardless if it was returning.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(scope) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
        {
            _totalResults = SearchHelper.ExecuteQuerySearch(query, Model.Divisions).ToList();
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
        {

            _totalResults = SearchHelper.ExecuteQuerySearch(query).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            _totalResults = new List<SearchItem>();
        }
```